# How to make Django view run further after sending back its response?

Tags: python, django

My interface must give users an option to start a long web-scraping operation, which could take from some minutes to a couple of hours. As this operation runs, it will persist data to the database. It's coded in this fashion:

```
def my_view(request):
    batch = BatchTable.objects.create(user=request.user)  # Batch model registers who started the operation
    try:
        long_running_operation(batch)  # How can THIS be made to run after response being sent?
    except Exception as ex:
        batch.fail = str(ex)
        batch.failed = datetime.now()
        batch.save()
    return JsonResponse({'success': 'True', 'message': 'Batch started'})


def long_running_operation(batch):
    list_response = requests.get('https://agiven.web.service/rest/api/objects')
    object_list = list_response.json()
    batch.total = len(object_list)
    batch.save()
    for object_entry in list_response.json():
        object_response = requests.get(f'https://agiven.web.service/rest/api/objects/{object_entry.id}')
        object_dict = object_response.json()
        object_dict['batch'] = batch  # to link the entry to the batch in which it was read and created
        ObjectTable.objects.create(**object_dict)  # to persist object data in the bd
        batch.progress += 1
        batch.save()
    batch.finalized = datetime.now()
    batch.save()
```

`my_view()` is hit by an AJAX request, but of course this request will hang until `long_running_operation()` has finished.

Is there some way of sending the response first from `my_view()` and continuing execution by only then calling `long_running_operation()`?

Comment: Make use of a tool like `Celery` that will asynchronously run a task: https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a *task queue* service, such as [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html), to execute the task in another thread/process.

Here is a minimal example, with the following dependencies:

- `pip3 install celery "celery[redis]"`
- `brew install redis` (macOS) or install manually from [here](https://redis.io/)

First create the file **`proj/proj/celery.py`**:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj', 
    broker_url = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
)

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Now create a **`tasks.py`** file in your app directory, and move `long_running_operation` there:

```
from proj.celery import app

@app.task
def long_running_operation(batch):
    ...
```

Next, call the task using **[`task.delay`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay)** from your view:

```
from myapp.tasks import long_running_operation

def my_view(request):
    batch = BatchTable.objects.create(user=request.user)
    long_running_operation.delay(batch)
    return JsonResponse({'success': 'True', 'message': 'Batch started'})
```

Finally, before you start your server, make sure you start a redis instance on your machine, by calling `redis-server` from the cli, then [start the worker](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker) by calling `celery -A proj worker -l info`.

In terms of performance and features, celery is certainly one of the *"best"* tools available for Django ATM, but it definitely adds an excessive amount of overhead for simple use cases.

I haven't tried it myself, but I've heard good things about **[`django-background-tasks`](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**, which might be a better alternative if you're app doesn't have a high demand.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I could, I would upvote your answer 100x , since you ran the extra mile and taught how to implement it. I'm novice in Django, so I really needed that. `django-background-tasks` was another precious indication, I guess I'll stick with it for the moment, due to its simpler approach.